# do we have to use static-content:deploy for every small change in our custom jascript in magento

Tags: admin, magento2

i am creating one custom javascript file in magento admin side.i need to use static-content:deploy every time to reflect the change in javascript .so it's taking very long time to see the output.so what is the standard way to use the custom javascript snippet

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion is to have that JS as online JS rather then in .JS file.

Comment: thank you for suggestion.may i know how to add that online js link in .xml file because i don't have .phtml file to that controller.